# Function that shortens a String based on a term/abbreviation mapping

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, hash-map

I have a function that takes a description as a `String` and returns a shortened version of the description.

The shortening is done by checking if a word matches the key of the `HashMap<String,String> map` and replaces the word by its abbreviation defined as the value in the `HashMap`. If the word cannot be found it in the `HashMap` it will not be replaced (it stays the same). If the value of a word is `<remove>` the word will be removed from the new description.

There can be multiple abbreviations for the same word.

Example:

> AUTOMATIC GAIN CONTROL --> AGC
>
> CONTROL --> CTRL

In any case the function should always take the abbreviation which takes the most words.

Consider this example mapping:

> AUTOMATIC GAIN CONTROL --> AGC
>
> CONTROL --> CTRL
>
> IDENTIFIER --> ID
>
> THE --> `<remove>`

The input `String`:

> The Automatic Gain Control identifier value

will result in the output `String`:

> AGC ID value

The `String`'s in the `HashMap` are all uppercase and the abbreviation in the output `String` should also be uppercase. However, any word that was not found in the `HashMap` should stay the same as it was in the input `String`.

My function seems to do the task correctly but I'm not sure if it could have been written better and/or more efficiently.

```
private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public static String shortenText(String input){

    ArrayList<String> listUpperCase = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String(input).toUpperCase().split(" ")));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));

    //Remove any words that map to <remove>
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        String value = map.get(listUpperCase.get(i));
        if (value!=null){
            if(value.equals("<remove>")){
                list.remove(i);
                listUpperCase.remove(i);
            }                   
        }
    }
    //Replace words by their abbreviation
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        StringBuilder tempBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String longestStringToShort="";
        int count=0;
        //Find abbreviations for terms with multiple words
        for(int k=0;k<list.size()-i;k++){
            tempBuilder.append(" "+listUpperCase.get(i+k));
            if(k==0) tempBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
            String value = map.get(tempBuilder.toString());
            if (value!=null){                   
                longestStringToShort = value;
                count = k;                                      
            }
        }
        if (!longestStringToShort.equals("")){
            builder.append(" "+longestStringToShort);
            i=i+count; 
        }
        else builder.append(" "+list.get(i));

    }

    builder.deleteCharAt(0);
    return builder.toString();

}
```

Comment: Will there be similar replacements? E.g. replacing `AUTOMATIC GAIN CONTROL` with `AGC` and `AUTOMATIC` with `AUTO`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes. One word can be a part of the key of multiple abbreviations. See my example with AUTOMATIC GAIN CONTROL and CONTROL. The function should always use the abbreviation that takes the most words as the key in the HashMap

Comment: @isADon ah yes, didn't see your `CONTROL` example... thanks for the clarification anyways. :)

Comment: Ever thinking of using a Trie? Only that for you it's word-based instead of character based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some observations (partly covered in [@RoToRa's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/100587/27975) answer):**

- A placeholder `String` such as `"<remove>"` doesn't communicate *at a glance* whether a subsequence can be removed or not. Consider if you are scanning through your code:

  ```
  map.put("Another Bored Cat", "ABC");
  map.put("Another Bad Coral", "<remove>");
  map.put("Another Berry Can", "ABC");
  ```

  You may miss out that `"Another Bad Coral"` needs to be removed, purely by looking at the length of the line. It's arguably easier to read as such:

  ```
  map.put("Another Bored Cat", "ABC");
  map.put("Another Bad Coral", "");
  map.put("Another Berry Can", "ABC");
  ```

  In this case, it also removes the ambiguity (as unlikely as that may seem initially) that `"Another Bad Coral"` will be substituted with `"<remove>"`.
- Not particularly efficient uses for `StringBuilder`, especially when you `builder.append(" " + aString)` when you can do `builder.apppend(' ').append(aString)`. Furthermore, you are also creating a `StringBuilder` for every tokenized word.
- Related to the previous point, your explicit concatentation of `" "` characters forces you to repetitively do `builder.deleteCharAt(0)`, which also leads to buggy derivation.
- Usage of `Map`/`HashMap` can be enhanced so as to reduce the explicit looping that you are currently doing by tokenizing the input `String`. As you mentioned, you want to "takes the most words as the key in the `HashMap`", so if there's a way to actually iterate in that order from the `Map`...

**Alternative implementation (Java 8 features ahead)**

You can then use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) with a suitable [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation to persist *and iterate* with. For example:

```
private static final Comparator<String> KEY_COMPARATOR = (s1, s2) -> {
    int diff = Integer.compare(s2.length(), s1.length());
    return diff == 0 ? s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) : diff;
};
```

Or in the form of an anonymous class:

```
private static final Comparator<String> KEY_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int diff = Integer.compare(s2.length(), s1.length());
        return diff == 0 ? s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) : diff;
    }
};
```

This literally does what is required: if the lengths of both `String`s are the same, we'll use a case-insensitive comparison between the both of them, else we simply rank the longer `String` to be *greater* than the other. This means that a `Map` such as:

```
private static final Map<String, String> MAPPER = getMapper();

private static Map<String, String> getMapper() {
    Map<String, String> mapper = new TreeMap<>(KEY_COMPARATOR);
    mapper.put("THE", "");
    mapper.put("AUTOMATIC", "AUTO");
    mapper.put("ZOOKEEPER", "ZK");
    mapper.put("AUTOMATIC GAIN CONTROL", "AGC");
    mapper.put("IDENTIFIER", "ID");
    return mapper;
}
```

Will give us the following desired iteration order:

```
// MAPPER.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.printf("%s => %s\n", key, value));
AUTOMATIC GAIN CONTROL => AGC
IDENTIFIER => ID
AUTOMATIC => AUTO
ZOOKEEPER => ZK
THE =>
```

With this `Map` implementation, the overall solution is half-complete. What is left is to replace any matching keys (as a subsequence) in the input `String` with the shortened value. For this, you can consider using [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) to perform the substitution on just *one* instance of `StringBuilder`:

```
private static String shorten(String input) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input);
    MAPPER.forEach((key, value) -> {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b" + key + "\\b").matcher(result);
        while (matcher.reset().find()) {
            result.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), value);
            if (value.isEmpty() && result.length() != 0) {
                result.deleteCharAt(Math.max(0, matcher.start() - 1));
            }
        }
    });
    return result.toString();
}
```

- Use a case-insensitive (`(?i)`) `Pattern` instance to apply on the `StringBuilder` via `Pattern.matcher(CharSequence)`. The [`\\b` word boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) is important to make sure we only match on a complete expression demarcated by whitespaces.
- Loop through each match, taking care to `reset()` the `Matcher` instance first.
- Replace the contents of the `StringBuilder` instance using the results `matcher.start()` and `matcher.end()`.
- For cases where we are removing text, we also need to remember to delete the previous character, *or the first*, so long as the `StringBuilder` instance is non-empty.

**Unit-testing**

In case this is not done yet, remember to [unit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit-testing) this method too! For example, using a combination of [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) and [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) matchers library to perform the required assertions:

```
@Test
public void testInput() {
    String test = "There is the Automatic Automatic Gain Control Zookeeper Identifier";
    assertThat(shorten(test + " " + test), 
                    equalsTo("There is AUTO AGC ZK ID There is AUTO AGC ZK ID"));
    // the middle whitespace is effectively trimmed away
    assertThat(shorten("the the"), equalsTo(""));
    assertThat(shorten("The Automatic Gain Control identifier value"),
                    equalsTo("AGC ID value"));
}
```

Comment: Very neat implementation but unfortunately I am forced to use Java 6. I marked it as the correct answer anyway since I did learn a lot from it and it does the task correctly.  Can you tell me why `builder.apppend(' ').append(aString)` is better than doing `builder.append(" " + aString)`?

Comment: Tip: it's not that hard to retrofit the Java 8 `forEach()` method (just loop explictly using `for (Entry<String, String> ...)` or convert the `KEY_COMPARATOR` lambda to an anonymous class (`new Comparator<String>() { ... }`). ;)

Comment: Whenever you do `" " + aString`, an implicit `StringBuilder` is also used for this concatenation. It's simply easier and more efficient to let the existing `StringBuilder` instance add the whitespace character (efficiency), then `aString` so that it can also figure out by itself whether it needs to resize or not.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Can you show me how to change the lambda to an anonymous class? I'm not able to get the syntax right for some reason

Comment: @isADon see updated answer.

Comment: There is a bug and I don't really know hot to fix it. With a map that maps "a" to "" (it will remove it) I get a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException at deleteChar() with the input String "xxxxxx a". ("xxxxxx" is not in the map)

Comment: @isADon hmms this is why we need unit testing. :D I'll see if I have a fix... do share if you have one too!

Comment: @isADon please see edited answer... think that should fix it.

Comment: hmm not really. The same input "xxxxxx a" gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Same happens with "xxxxxx a xxxxxx" (which was working before). The problem is mappings between a single character and "" (which means it will be removed in the output)

Comment: @isADon unfortunately I can't replicate the 'bug' anymore with my edit, which boils down to `Math.max(0, matcher.start() - 1)`. Can you please test again? Or perhaps start a quick question over at StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't the time for an extensive review. Here some quick remarks:

Use better variable names. Just `map` for the main replacement map is bad.

Your code does have a bug. Try running `shortenText("THE THE");`. Hint: Removing elements from a list while looping over it is dangerous.

Don't keep two lists with the same contents. Just use one list and use `toUpperCase` where needed.

`new String(...)` is almost always unnecessary.

I would expect to be able to remove whole phrases with spaces, instead of just single words, just like you can replace phrases with an abbreviation. Actually you shouldn't need to handle the search for removement phrases differently than replacement phrases, just the action you take after finding them would be different.

Using a placeholder String such as `"<remove>"` is a bad idea. It would be best to use a different type, or in this simple case just use `null`.

Splitting everything into words is unnecessarily complex. Just search the phrases in the input string (for example with the `String` method `indexOf`).

Comment: Why do you suggest not splitting my input string in to words? I'm not sure I understand your implementation with `indexOf`. Just to clarify: My map has a size of about 500. 90% of the entries are mappings between a single word and its abbreviation. The input String has a maximum length of 50-60 characters.

Comment: `"<remove>"` only maps to single words (example: "The", "an", "a"). I get the bug you pointed out. How would I avoid this problem?

Comment: Before I answer those questions, I have a question for you: Is this  practice code or production code? If it's practice code, you should be willing to "bend" the requirements and be able assume things about the input that could actually break in a real production environment.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact definition of production code so let’s call it pre-production code maybe? But you are right, since the user will be able to edit the mapping file (which will be read in by the program to populate the HashMap) at his free will, it is useful to consider parts that might break the current logic of the code.

Comment: I didn't get around to post more yesterday. The reason I asked was, because for production code your problem description isn't complete enough in my opinion and I wanted to know how much work I should put in considering edge cases. However the solution of h.j.k. has covered a lot of that in the mean time. So just for completeness, here my practice code version I came up with: http://ideone.com/jikhRL